# Google Sheet ISBETWEEN doesn't recognize named range?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, error-handling, formula, named-ranges

Column A is named "Quantity", which works in a simple formula:
[image]

I'm getting an error when attempting to use a named range in ISBETWEEN formula:
[image]

I verified that ISBETWEEN works when I use cell reference A2 instead of named range Quantity:
[image]

Any thoughts how I can fix?

Comment: Is the range assigned to your named range `Quantity` A:A? Or A2:A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your named range `Quantity` has its range set to **A1:A** but you are entering it in ***row 2***, so error says there is no room in **A2:A** for **A1:A** unless you add a row but when you do it's the same coz you can't fit 3 keys into 2 keyholes (from one side each of course)

*As seen on this sample:*

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

See my comment to your original post.

Assuming that your named range `Quantity` is applied to the entire range A:A (and not A2:A), delete *everything* from Col B (including the header) and then place the following formula in cell B1:

`=ArrayFormula( {"Test"; IF(A2:A="",, ISBETWEEN( FILTER(Quantity, ROW(Quantity)>1), 1, 5) ) } )`

This one formula will create the header text (which you can change *within the formula* if you like) and all results for all valid, non-null rows.

`FILTER(Quantity, ROW(Quantity)>1)` is necessary to limit the full range of the named range `Quantity` to only those elements whose row is greater than (row) 1; this is because your *results* begin in Row 2.

You only need this *one* formula. As you add more data into Col A, the formula will process it.